# Pass one of many objects from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hidden-field, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

In an ASP.Net Core web app, I'm passing a `List<Parameter>` to a view via `ViewBag.Parameters`. The view also has a `SelectParameterViewModel` that consists of one property only, an `int ParameterId`. The objects are then displayed in a table like so (I skipped straight to tbody as the view works fine from a cosmetic perspective):

```
@model WebApp.Models.ReportViewModels.SelectParameterViewModel
[...]
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Parameters)
    {
    <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-1">
            <form asp-controller="Report" asp-action="Launch">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <input asp-for="@Model.ParameterId" type="hidden" value="@item.Id" />
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Select" />
            </form>
        </td>
        <td class="col-xs-8">@item.Description</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">
            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
            <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

I would like the user to click on the button of the chosen table-row and submit either that row's `Parameter` (preferred) or the `Parameter`'s `Id`, like I tried to do in this case. I would then do the same with the `<a>` tags on the third column. The point is that I don't want the user to simply type `/Report/Launch/id` and run the report, as each user would have its own sets of parameters and should not be allowed to use any of the others', and the ViewBag only contains the list of its `Parameter`. I can change the view model and/or the receiving controller's argument depending on the solution, both would work. I tried a few versions of the above html, but none would work, while the above returns `ParameterId` with value `0`.
I couldn't find a similar scenario in other SO questions. There were some solutions that involved JavaScript and, correct me if I'm wrong, but that would still show the `ParameterId` value in the webpage source. While that would be sort-of-ok in this specific case, I have other cases where I definitely would not want that to happen.
What would be an elegant solution to achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: You handle security in the controller, not the url. If the current user does not have permission to view something with a particular ID, then you deny them access to it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you Stephen. I guess I was trying to solve the problem in the wrong place.